# Sd card not working after unplugging from the Pi

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, raspbian-jessie

I just got two micro sd cards, I wrote latest jessy raspbian on the first, then pluged it into the Pi, it was good until I unplug it from the Pi, then trying to open it again on my PC, the PC could not detect it (windows, ubuntu, and my android phone none of them detected the card) I then resigned to the fact that the card may be just dead. and tryed with the 2nd sd card, same thing happened.

And when I plug back the cards on the raspberry, raspberry does not boot.

So, what do you think about that. Any idea about how can I fix my cards or how can I run latest jessy and be able to unplug the card and use it somewhere else. I am affraid to try other cards, because it might just happen again (if it happens twice I don't see why it won't happen the third time)

I noticed this behavior: When I open device managment,and then plug the card it shows as USB mass storage for few seconds then disappears. same on disk management

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Plugging your card into a working Linux system would be helpful to diagnose this. Unlike windows, Linux gives you an error message when a device malfunctions.

Comment: Linux (ubuntu) can't detect the card, and android can't detect the card. all I got in disk management on ubuntu is no media, when attempting to eject the medium inside the adaptor, I got: udisks-error-quark, 0

Comment: But what does Linux tell when you plug the card in? There should be something in the logs, unless the card is totally dead.

Comment: which logs are talking about please ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've lost the partition table.

You can repair your SD card with a built-in windows utility called `diskpart`: [instructions here](https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/SD-card-repair-with-diskpart.html).

**Summary:**

from the run menu, run `diskpart`

in diskpart:

execute `list disk`

select your sd card eg. `select disk 1` if it appears as disk 1

execute: `clean`

execute: `create partition primary`

If either command fails, just reattempt it. Sometimes they fail the first try.

quit diskpart. Your SD card will appear in the explorer. Try to open your SD card, you will be prompted to format it.

---

Are you making sure to safely shutdown your Pi before you pull the SD card out? You should always have access on Windows to the ~100MB `boot` partition of an SD card running Raspbian

Comment: neither clean nor create partition primary worked after many many attemps

Comment: When I open device managment,and then plug the card it shows as USB mass storage for few seconds then disappears. same on disk management

Comment: I had an SD card unreadable like this. I used [Etcher](http://www.etcher.io) to flash another image on the card and it was fine.